# Python If Statement Evaluates to True, but does not execute?

Tags: python

```
ranked = [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10]
player = [5, 25, 50, 120]



def climbingLeaderboard(ranked, player):
    ranks = []
    for score in player:
        iteration = 0
        temp = 0
        ranks.append(0)
        for rank in ranked:

            if rank == temp:
                continue

            elif iteration == 0 & score >= rank:
                ranks[player.index(score)] += 1

            elif iteration == 0 & score < rank:
                ranks[player.index(score)] += 2

            elif score < rank:
                ranks[player.index(score)] += 1

            elif score == rank:
                break

            iteration += 1
            temp = rank

    print(ranks)


climbingLeaderboard(ranked, player)
```

This body of code should give the respective ranks of [6,4,2,1] but instead yields [6,4,2,2]. When I ran the debugger, the issue is that when 120 is being evaluated as one of the player scores,

`elif iteration == 0 & score < rank: ranks[player.index(score)] += 2`

`elif iteration == 0 & score >= rank: ranks[player.index(score)] += 1`

Python thinks that 120 is less than 100, it thinks score is less than the rank, and evaluates to the first statement instead of the second statement, which is the True one. I've gone into the debugger to make sure this is the issue, it is. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Use `and`, not `&`.

Comment: You want `and`, not `&` (bitwise and).

Comment: Also, use enumerate instead of a counter variable

Comment: `&` has higher precedance than comparison operators, so it's being treated as `elif iteration == (0 & score) >= rank:`. `0 & score` is always `0`.

Comment: If there are duplicate scores, `player.index(score)` will always return the first index, not the current index in the iteration.

Comment: Barmar, that's impressive you caught that, thank you.